# Getting PHP Notice: Undefined index: password_clear in joomla when using plugin other then joomla login

Tags: php, joomla

I am getting 
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  password_clear 
when I use any plugin other then joomla's login plugin to log-in the user. 
In joomla database, we are not storing any user's data. so I have got a custom plugin, which will do the check for user's credentials through a web service call.

The credentials are checked good, and joomla does show the user has logged in, and rest of the things are also working fine. But my logs are filled with the above Notices!

Any one faced such problem or any hints or directions for me?

Thanks for help in advance,
Tanmay

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

1. Edit php.ini and set error_reporting to `E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR`
2. Edit the plugin code and test the presence of password_clear before using it.

Here's an example how to do the testing part:

```
$clear = $_POST['password_clear']; /* old */
$clear = empty($_POST['password_clear']) ? '' : $_POST['password_clear']; /* fixed */
```

or:

```
if ($_POST['password_clear'] == 'x') {...} /* old */
if (! empty($_POST['password_clear']) && $_POST['password_clear'] == 'x') {...} /* fixed */
```

Comment: The password_clear is been used in the joomla core code in /plugins/user/joomla.php, As its the core file, I am sure everything should have been taken care of. But as I am going to prepare a plugin for login, I do not want to touch the core files, as later I would be deploying this plugin to many other joomla instances.

Answer (score 0):

@JMZ, your reply did gave me some ideas of looking into the stuff, and I got the solution.
I am not user, if the changes I did are valid, but it works for me. 
I basically grabbed the gmail.php login plugin as the base for creating my own plugin.

Now on the success I had to add
$response->password_clear = ""; to the response object, so that at least it has a reference and will not give me a notice of undefined index.

Hope some one will be helped. Or if some one has a better understanding on this, please do let me know.

Thanks,
Tanmay

Comment: Hiding or masking this error is one thing, but I can't help but feel that if this array index is used unchecked in the core then it's perhaps integral to something else (as you hint in your comment above)  - so, what is this actually used for?

Comment: @w3d: it seems that password_clear is used in the user object handled by joomla. Which seems to be executing cascading functions, and some where it also has to clear the password. One exact place where I found joomla is using it is in resetting of password